# Can I use jQuery prefilters to detect onreadystatechange events where readyState==3?

Tags: jquery, comet, http-streaming, onreadystatechange

I'm trying to implement the XHR streaming Comet technique in jQuery, but am having some trouble detecting the `onreadystatechange` event.  I'm using Firefox 4.0.1.

I'm using [prefilters](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Prefilters) (available since jQuery 1.5) to modify the native XHR object, specifically to add an event handler to the `onreadystatechange` event.  I've got a crude implementation of that at http://jsfiddle.net/Rdx6f/.  That code appends to the document the XHR object's `readyState` and `responseText` attributes when the `onreadystatechange` event is fired.  Oddly, however, it only seems to detect the `onreadystatechange` event when `readyState` is 1.

In other words, jQuery seems to be detecting the `onreadystatechange` event when the XMLHttpRequest object is in state "opened" (readyState 1), but not when the XHR object is in state "headers received" (readyState 2), "loading" (readyState 3), nor "done" (readyState 4).

Oddly, if I `alert()` in the event handler, then I *do* see the `onreadystatechange` handling when readyState is 1, 2, 3 and 4.  See http://jsfiddle.net/Rdx6f/1/.  Same code as http://jsfiddle.net/Rdx6f/, just `alert()`ing instead of appending to the document.

I can also detect `onreadystatechange` events when `readyState` is 1, 2, 3 or 4 in native JavaScript -- see http://jsfiddle.net/d7vaH/.  (That code is taken almost verbatim from Dylan Schiemann's implementation of XHR streaming on page 115 of the book "Even Faster Websites".)

Am I simply doing something wrong here, like using jQuery's Ajax prefilters wrong or making a JavaScript mistake?  Is this perhaps a bug in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI: I looked into this quite deeply and it turns out that jQuery (since 1.5) uses the onreadystatechange event internally. The consequence of this is that jQuery will **always** write it's internal function to the onreadystatechange event, overwriting whatever you set it to. This happens whenever the AJAX call is actually sent, which means the function you wrote for onreadystatechange will work until that time (which means it will work until readyState = 1, but not longer).

This is the proposed workaround at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/tBTW2/

At the moment, I cannot see a different (better) workaround without either not using jQuery (or going back to 1.4.4 or lower version, where it works perfectly) or editing the jQuery code (because as it is right now they will always overwrite whatever you try to hook in).

However, in upcoming versions (most likely in 1.8), the jQuery team are planning on implementing support for triggering events depending on the different readyStates. They will use Deferreds in some way.

This is the ticket that keeps this upcoming change:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9883

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the prefiltering done correctly linked from the jQuery bugzilla bug [#8327](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8327),

http://jsfiddle.net/d8ckU/1/

Comment: I wouldn't say that's quite it.  The code I linked to in http://jsfiddle.net/Rdx6f/ was derived from the jsfiddle you refer to.  However, the jsfiddle you linked to uses setInterval() to poll the responseText attribute, which seems inefficient.  I'm looking for a way to attach an event handler to the onreadystatechange event of the underlying XHR object.

Comment: @user461155 Yeah, I know, the linked code, unfortunately is the official jQuery response for accessing the readystate == 3 event. :( [#1172](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1172) is the relevant bug. You would need to make a plug in for anything more.